# Can noise back-feed through an op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, emc

Take a non-inverting op-amp, where the output is connected directly (0 Ω) to the inverting input. If noise from EMI exists on the output, would it be possible for the noise to be seen on the non-inverting input of the op-amp?

Comment: Of course. You referring to a " non-inverting op-amp" and then proceeding to wire it up as a voltage follower is incorrect though. Just simply say "opamp". Opamps are neither inverting or noninverting. Opamp *circuits* are inverting and non-inverting.

Comment: Is this a practical real-life situation?  If so, please post the model of the OpAmp, and the characteristics of the noise.  Or, is this more of an academic question?

Comment: @DKNguyen, correct, an op-amp setup as a non-inverting amplifier circuit.

Comment: @NickAlexeev, yes but I cannot provide a model, so let us treat it an as an academic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it could, however it would likely be small. The output resistance of the op-amp at reasonable frequencies is something like 100 ohms in that configuration and there is some small coupling between the inputs so what appears on one input can couple to the other if there is some source impedance.

Here is a simulation of a typical precision op-amp (OPA177) with a 100kHz 1V signal applied to the output (assuming the source has a 50Ω source impedance). Also 100kΩ source impedance on the grounded non-inverting input.

[image]

Here you can see a ~100uV peak signal measured at the non-inverting input.

At lower frequencies such as 10kHz or lower there will be less effect. At somewhat higher frequencies such as a few MHz the behavior will be similar.

Comment: I'm a bit dubious about whether this simulation would hold up in a real circuit. Would be interesting to try with a few real opamps. What happens if you take out the 50 ohms?

Comment: @danmcb Similar. It indeed may not be accurate. Certainly would vary with op-amp type and might be difficult to measure.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: V3 and R1 can be located on the other side of the amplifier close to the inverting input. The result will be exactly the same. The signal that you provide on the output travels to the input though the feedback wire not through the op-amp.

Comment: @RussellH It travels between the inputs through the op-amp, n'est ce pas?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: From input to input is not "back-feed" through the op-amp. Any differential voltage appearing across the inputs will travel forward through the op-amp to the output.

Comment: @RussellH given that output and - input are directly connected in this configuration (usually by a very short trace as they are adjacent pins on most parts), it is reasonable to interpret "input" as meaning the + input. We are talking about circuit input and output, not the names of the pins on the datasheet.

Comment: @danmcb: Your interpretation is not what the OP has said.. It is very clearly stated what is meant by the inputs.

Comment: "would it be possible for the noise to be seen on the non-inverting input of the op-amp?"  - which part of this is unclear?

Comment: I believe this best demonstrates what I was asking. Thank you, Spehro! This helps with understanding the potential effect the output can have on the inputs, and the rest of the circuit can use superposition principle for finding total effect.

Answer (score 2):

If you have EMI on the output, you have to first ask how is it getting in there? Two main possibilities come to mind:

1. the output trace is long and next to a source that is emitting a lot of interference (perhaps a switching PSU or similar), maybe at a frequency where the opamp has a higher output impedance (i.e. decreased ability to drive the load). At any rate the source must be strong w.r.t the opamp's ability to drive the load for this to happen.
2. Through the supplies (quite common issue).

It's not really possible to answer the OP's question with any certainty without a better knowledge of the pathology involved, but these are the two most likely cases, and in both there is a pretty good chance that source might get onto the input terminals as well (if it's via supplies, it's almost a certainty). (In my experience, once you have this kind of issue, the interference will often tend to get all over the place.)

So yes, it is most certainly possible, is the short answer.

Comment: The EMI is coming from an external source, not from input, hence my question on backfeeding.

Comment: ok, but is it really getting in through the output trace or the supplies? have you confirmed (e.g. by cutting/shortening the output trace and seeing if it is still there. (the fact that it is EMI means it is an "external source"  but that says nothing about the path by which it gets in your circuit.)

Comment: The original question is asking if a noisy signal applied to one input of an op-amp can go through the op-amp to the other input. The standard undergraduate level assumption is that op-amps try to make their inputs an equal potential level, so maybe a better way of phrasing is: is it a possible that noise on one input can drive the op-amp to cause the noise to appear on the other input? The noise is not coming from a source entering the input (non-inverting input from my example).

Comment: An ideal op amp does indeed try to keep their inputs at the same potential, but the only way it has to do so is by adjusting the output voltage. If you think this through, it's implications on your question are fairly obvious I think. However a real opamp has signal paths between terminals which are not considered for an ideal one. This also has implications (although that is not perhaps what you intended in your question, it is relevant to it).

Answer (score -1):

Short answer, No. It cannot travel *through* the op-amp without damaging it. The noise will travel around the op-amp through the feedback <s>components</s> wire. So yes the noise will appear on the non-inverting input.

UPDATE: In every closed loop configuration, the voltage on one input will also appear on the other input due to standard op-amp input action. Any voltage differential as a result will travel forward though the amplifier to the output.

I speculate that EMI on the output must be significant since \$R_{out}\$ is very small. It is more likely that the non-inverting input will be more sensitive to EMI which would then appear on the output by op-amp action.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The down voters need to reconsider their electronics ;-)

Comment: the statement that it "cannot travel through the opamp without damaging it" is questionable at best. Coupling through internal circuitry in unintended ways can and does happen and certainly does not always result in damage.

Comment: @danmcb: In many (most) circumstances I would agree. , But the "output is connected directly (0 Ω) to the inverting input".  This wire would be in parallel with any other unintended path. So in order for any path to have precedence over a short there would need to be damage.